# env.getProperty not working Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring, spring-4

I am loading properties file using spring

```
  <bean id="appProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
         <property name="locations" value="classpath:/sample.properties" />
          <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```

when i am getting property value using

`@Value("${testkey}")` its working fine.

but when i am trying to get using env

```
@Resource
 private Environment environment;

environment.getProperty("testkey") // returning null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` does not add the properties from its `locations` to the `Environment`. With Java config, you can use `@PropertySource` to do that.

Comment: is there anyway to do via xml in spring 4 ?

Comment: @invariant I don't know of a clean way to do it by just declaring a bean. You could create your own `ApplicationContextAware` bean which adds them.

Answer (score 1):

If any one want to achieve  this without using @PropertySource

use ApplicationContextInitializer interface and its companion, the contextInitializerClasses servlet context param.

add this in web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>com.test.MyInitializer</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and define your Initializer

```
public class MyInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableWebApplicationContext> {
    public void initialize(ConfigurableWebApplicationContext ctx) {
        PropertySource ps = new ResourcePropertySource(new ClassPathResource("sample.properties")); // handle exception
        ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(ps);
    }
}
```

Reference : [Spring 3.1 M1: Unified Property Management](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/)