# How to configure Spring annotation and xml together with struts2

Tags: java, xml, spring, struts2, spring-4

We have existing spring application integrated with struts2, and we are using xml based config ..

but i found one limitation
[env.getProperty not working Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895908/env-getproperty-not-working-spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer)

so i decided to use both annotation and xml in app for now and in future i want to remove xml .

Currently my web.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID_1" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>eZair_book</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
     <context-param>
      <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
      <param-value>
         org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
      </param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>com.invariant.spring</param-value>
    </context-param> 
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>  
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>       
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and my application config class is

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({ "classpath*:/applicationContext.xml"} )
@PropertySource({ "classpath:sample.properties" })
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

now my application deploying fine ,but when i try to run my app struts2 not able to see action classes defined in spring

i am getting following error 
Unable to instantiate Action, myAction

```
           Unable to instantiate Action, myAction,  defined for 'book' in namespace '/'myAction
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:316)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:397)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:194)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:37)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:552)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myAction
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:204)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:688)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:667)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:119)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:584)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:152)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.getClassInstance(ObjectFactory.java:128)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.getClassInstance(SpringObjectFactory.java:233)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:153)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.DefaultActionFactory.buildAction(DefaultActionFactory.java:22)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:297)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: What's the full stack trace?

Comment: Are you using the Spring plugin? What does the action bean configuration look like?

Comment: yes i am using plugin , app is working fine if i don't combine annoatation and xml , my action bean looks like this <bean id="myAction" class="com.invariant.MyAction" scope="prototype" parent="baseAction">

Comment: Your application can't find the classes, thus you have not that classes on the classpath. Add the classes to the classpath, so the classloader is able bootstrap them.

Comment: @invariant: Are you sure beans are being found/initialized? This seems a bit odd to me `"classpath*:/applicationContext.xml"`.

Comment: @AleksandrM thats the root cause :( , i fixed that path everything works fine ,thanks alot :)

Comment: @invariant: Glad you've solved that. You are welcome.

Comment: @AleksandrM Why don't you post answer???

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your myAction in struts.xml something like this:

```
<action name="myAction" class="foo.bar.subpackage.myAction" method="execute">
<result name="error">/actions/error.jsp</result>
<result name="success">/actions/success.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Change method="execute" to your actual method name.