# Get all spring properties from Dispatcher

Tags: java, spring

I am able to get some property using injection. But when I use spring Environment, I cannot find it. My final goal is it find all defined properties and search between them by prefix. None of answers in [Spring: access all Environment properties as a Map or Properties object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23506471/1639556) worked for me.

This is my `Dispatcher` configuration:

```
<bean id="proxyProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:device.properties</value>
            <value>file:/${user.dir}/device-local.properties</value>
            <value>file:${smartpos.config.dir:/etc/pos}/device.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="properties" ref="proxyProperties"/>
    <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="!device{"/>
    <property name="placeholderSuffix" value="}"/>
</bean>
```

Injection with fixed value works fine:

```
@Service
public class DeviceService {

@Value(value = "!device{application.version.pattern}")
public void setVersion(String apiVersion) throws DeviceAPIException { }
```

Looking for the property in `Environment` does not work, I cannot locate it:

```
@Autowired
public DeviceService(Environment env) {
    String s = env.getProperty("application.version.pattern");
    s = env.getProperty("!device{application.version.pattern}");
}
```

I have opened the `Environment` and there were 5 property sources like System or JNDI but none of them contained my properties from `device.properties` file. This may be the reason why no answer from linked question work. They all list system properties but my properties are missing.

I run this application in jetty using jetty-maven-plugin.

Comment: does your  String s = env.getProperty("application.version.pattern"); print the expected value?

Comment: both statements retun null

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895908/env-getproperty-not-working-spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer

Comment: The PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer doesnot add values to the Environment object

Comment: Hmm. Is there any chance to get all defined properties so I can iterate them?